# Passing an enum to a method in a service

Tags: c#, wcf, enums

I have a very simple WCF service running on a sharepoint server that has a `ServiceContract` that looks something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface iSPTest
{
    [OperationContract]
    Stream Process(Stream input);
}
```

This works fine and I'm able to use `svcutil` to generate a proxy and a config file. However, I wanted to change it to take an enum:

```
    [OperationContract]
    Stream Process(Stream input, MyEnumType foo);
```

With the `enum` defined:

```
[DataContract]
public enum MyEnumType 
{
    [EnumMember]
    Default = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    Foo,
    [EnumMember]
    Bar
};
```

However, when I do this, I can no longer get the proxy to generate. I get an error:

```
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://myserver/_vti_
bin/SPTest/SPTest.svc'.

The requested service, 'http://myserver/_vti_bin/SPTest/SPTest.svc' could not
be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.
```

It seems like this should be a simple thing. I've tried adding `ServiceKnownType` to the `ServiceContract`, but that didn't seem to help. Why does it seem unable to pick up the enum type? For bonus points, is it possible to use an existing enum in an assembly that the server references but the client does not? Because in that case it wouldn't be possible to mark the `enum` with `DataContract`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the enumeration. This is to do with the concept of WCF streaming. You have a web method that accepts two parameters first of which is of type `Stream`. This is not supported because the parameter that holds the data to be streamed can exists as the only one in the method. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I think that with your current OperationContract you would get `InvalidOperationException` if you tried to create a service host, saying that *the operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream.*

You can workaround this by introducing new type and encapsulating your stream and enum inside of it.

Comment: Ok, that sounds right. Searching some more, this: http://cm-bloggers.blogspot.com/2011/06/wcf-pattern-passing-additional-data-to.html looks like about the right approach.

Comment: Interestingly, when using `MySteam` custom message contract it wouldn't work if I had `Stream Process(MySteam input);`, it had to be `MySteam Process(MySteam input);` and the proxy insisted on creating a method with a signature of `void Process(ref myEnum foo, ref Stream input);`